# How can I print a RTF formatted String to a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, formatting, paintcomponent, jtextcomponent

I have my **custom JComponent** which do a lot of drawing operations.

They also include drawStrings for text paragraphs, but now Id like to format the text (in a seperate window with jtextpane or another RTF editor) (bold, font-size, align, font-color, lists) and show this formatted text in my own component.

Id like to do that without bufferedimages because if i have a big jcomponent full with images I would get a overflow error (RAM)

Something like with AttributedString could work, but how?

I don't really know how to get the **RTF-Text** out of the Jtextpane (or if there is a better editor plz tell me) and **draw it in the "paintComponent(Graphics g)" method**.

The Editor is just used to format the text easily, not for the presentation (which is done with my own component)

Can anyone help me please?

---

Thanks for your help,

so i create an AttributeString and then apply the RTF-formattings in it?

do you know how I can extrude the RTF information to an adequate AttributedString? e.g. a function which transforms the formatted text to an AttributedString like

```
public AttributedString getAttrString(String plainRTF){
   ...
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: there is a link in my question to a sample implementation of such function. It is a bit simplified but should give you a general idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this custom AdvancedRTFEditorKit 
http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the structure of the underlying [Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) to get to the actual elements. Each [Element](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Element.html) has a set of attributes you can access with [getAttributes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Element.html#getAttributes%28%29).

You can build `AttributedString` using `document.getText()` and applying corresponding styles using `AttributedString.addAttribute()` method.

Then draw the string on `Graphics`. Check out this [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Media/2DText/style.html) that uses TextLayout to render the AttributedString.

Take a look at `styledDocumentToAttributedString()` method [here](http://code.google.com/p/dmdirc/source/browse/trunk/src/com/dmdirc/ui/swing/textpane/TextPane.java?spec=svn1987&r=1987). It may be already implements what you need; it depends on the complexity of your string. Also, this [discussion](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=5362678) may be useful.